# Cannot read property '__k' of null - FullCalendar + Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar plugin for Angular 11.
I keep getting the error "Cannot read property '__k' of null". Seems it is happening when calendar.render() is called. But can't get to the bottom of it. Any help is much appreciated.

This is my ts file:

```
export class FullCalendarComponent {
    public calendar: Calendar | undefined;
    calendarEl: any;

    calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {

        slotMinTime: '07:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '19:00:00', 
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        height: 680,
        events: [
            this.currentEvents,
        ],

        headerToolbar: {
            start: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        firstDay: 1,
        initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
        weekends: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this),
        allDaySlot: false,

       }
    ngOnInit(): void {

        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl!, this.calendarOptions);
        calendar!.render();

    }
```

And my html file

```
  <div class="calendar">
        <full-calendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
    </div>
```

[Here is a screenshot of the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQkEP.png)

Comment: calendar!.render(); Good afternoon. I am seeing an "!" in the render() method invocation. Is that expected? Please advise.

Comment: just a non-null-assertion to avoid error stating that calendar cannot be null. 
But the mistake is still there even when "!" is omitted.

Comment: I got it. Please give me half day. Let me try it locally and see what I am getting. Many thanks.

Comment: Please review my answer below. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error is there because `calendarEl` is null. Declare `calendar` somewhere before that function if you need to access it globally. After the line where you define `calendarEl`, wrap everything in the conditional check

```
  var calendar;
   let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
   if (calendarEl != null) {
        let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl!, this.calendarOptions);
        calendar!.render();
   }
});
```

Comment: This error happens if calendarEl is not null also.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on my local box. The only thing is I did not invoke the .render() within the OnInit(). Because we are specifying the Calendar control with the HTML markup. I have checked the code into my GitHub repository and given the link below. Please let me know if you need any assitance.

```
<div class="calendar">
        <full-calendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
    </div>
```

URL: https://github.com/vishipayyallore/mini-projects-2021/tree/master/Projects/5_GettingStartedWithRouting

[image]